# Get rectangle out of array of points

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation, signal-processing, gpuimage

Using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), I am able to detect corners of a book/page in an image. But sometimes, it will pass more than 4 points, in which case I will need to process and figure out the best rectangle out of these points. Here's an example:

[image]

What's the most efficient way to figure out the best rectangle in this case? 
Thanks

Comment: I wonder if you could use an opening or closing operation as a first step in order to eliminate some of the smaller-scale features that it detects. You might also be able to process the image at a lower resolution using the corner detector to pick out only larger-scale features. This won't completely eliminate the extraneous points, but it might help.

Comment: Hi 0xSina, I also want to do the same thing (to detect corners of a book/page in an image) with GPUImage. How you did this ? Which filter you used?

Comment: @IOSDev I had mixed results using several filters in GPUImage so I went with openCV.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using a corner detection algorithm, then you can filter results based on the relative strength of the detected corner. The contrast at the book corners relative to your current background appears to be much stronger than the contrast at the point found in the wood grain. Are there relative magnitudes associated with each point, or do you just get the points? Setting thresholds for edge strengths can mean a lot of fiddling unless the intensities of the foreground and background are relatively constant.

Your sample image could be blurred or morphed. For example, the right morphological "close" on light pixels could eliminate the texture in the wood grain without having an effect on the size and shape of the book. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology)

Another possibility is to shrink the image to a much smaller size and then perform detection on that. Resizing the image will tend to wipe out tiny details such as whatever wood grain pattern is currently being detected.

Picking the right lens and lighting can make the image easier to process. Try to simplify the image as much as possible before processing it. As mentioned above, "dark field" lighting that would illuminate just the book edges would present a much simpler image for processing. Writing down the constraints can make it more obvious which solution will be most robust and simplest to implement. Finding any rectangle anywhere in an image is very difficult; it's much easier to find a light rectangle on a dark background if the rectangle is at least 100 x 100 pixels in size, rotated no more than 15 degrees from square to the image edges, etc.

More involved solutions can be split into two approaches:

1. Solving the problem using given only 4 or more (x,y) points.
2. Using a different image processing technique altogether for the sample image.

**1. Solving the program given only the points**
If you generally only have 5 or 6 points, and if you are confident that 4 of those points will belong to the corners of the rectangles that you want, then you can try this:

1. Find the convex hull of all points. The convex hull is the N-gon that completely encompasses all points. If the points were pegs sticking up, and if you stretched a rubber band around them and let it snap into place, then the final shape of the rubber band is a convex hull. Algorithms that find convex hulls typically return a list of points that ordered counterclockwise from the bottom leftmost point.
2. Make a copy of your point list and remove points from the copy until only four points remain. These four remaining points will still be ordered counterclockwise.
3. Calculate the angle formed by each set of three successive points: points 1, 2, 3, then 2, 3, 4, then 3, 4, 1, and so on.
4. If an angle is outside a reasonable tolerance--less than 70 degrees or greater than 110 degrees--skip back to step 2 and remove the next point (or set of points).
5. Store the min and max angles for each set of 4 points.
6. Repeat steps 2 - 6, removing a different point (or points) each time.
7. Track the set of points for which the min and max angles are closest to 90 degrees.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

There are a number of other checks and constraints that could be introduced. For example, if the point-to-point distances for 3 successive points in the convex hull (pts N to N+1, and N+1 to N+2) are close to the expected width and height of the book, then you might mark these as known good points and only test the remaining points to see which is the fourth point.

The technique above can get unwieldy if you get quite a few points, but it may work if two or three of the book corner points are expected to be found on the convex hull.

For any geometric problem, I always recommend checking out GeometricTools.com, which has a lot of great, optimized source code for all sorts of problems. It's very handy to have the book as well, especially if you can find a cheap copy using AddAll.com.

http://www.geometrictools.com/

**2. Other image processing techniques for your sample image**
Although I could be wrong, it appears that GPUImage doesn't have many general-purpose image processing algorithms. Some other image processing algorithms could make this problem much simpler to solve.

Though there isn't space to go into it here, one of the keys to successful image processing is appropriate lighting. Make sure you're lighting is consistent. A diffuse light that evenly illuminates the book and the background would work well. You can simplify the problem using funkier lighting: if you have four lights (or a special ring light), you can provide horizontal illumination from the top, bottom, left, and right that will cause the edges of the book to appear bright and other surfaces to appear dark. 
http://www.benderassoc.com/mic/lighting/nerlite/Darkfield.htm

If you can use some other GPU libraries to do image processing, then one of the following techniques could work nicely:

1. Connected component labeling (a.k.a. finding blobs). It shouldn't be too hard to use either binary thresholding or a watershed algorithm to separate the white blob that is the book from the rest of the background. Once the blob for the book is identified, finding the corners is easier. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) In OpenCV you can find the "contours."
2. Generate an list of edge points, then have four separate line-fitting tools search from top to bottom, right to left, bottom to top, and left to right to find the four strong (and mostly straight) edges associated with the book. In your sample image, though, either the book cover is slightly warped or the camera lens has introduced barrel distortion.
3. Use a corner detector designed to find light corners on a dark background. If you will always be looking for a white book on a wood grain background, you can create a detector to find white corners on a brown background.
4. Use a Hough technique to find the four strongest lines in the image. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform)

The algorithmic technique that works best will depend on your constraints: are you looking for rectangles only of a certain size? is the contrast between foreground and background consistent? can you introduce lighting to simplify the appearance of the image? and so on.